# Replacing certain elements of an array based on a given index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have three numpy arrays:

```
Arr1 = [9,7,3,1]       (1 x 4 array)
Arr2 = [[14,6],[13,2]] (2 x 2 array)
Arr3 = [0,2]           (1 x 2 array)
```

I need to replace the elements in Arr1 with the elements in Arr2 with the corresponding indices given in Arr3, such that the output would be:

```
Output_Arr = [[14,6],[7],[13,2],[1]]
```

I've written some code that I think is a good start, but it's not working. No errors or anything, just the Arr1 is not updating as if the criteria is not satisfied:

```
dim1 = len(Arr1)
dim2 = len(Arr2)
dim3 = len(Arr3)

for i in range(dim1):
    for j in range(dim3):
        if i==Arr3[j]:
            Arr1[i] = Arr2[j]
        else:
            Arr1[i] = Arr1[i]
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to go about this?

Comment: output_arr cannot be numpy array, as all lines don't have the same length. Could you clarify? (I mean: are you ok if it's just a list of list? or do you want zeros as fill_values ?)

Comment: @Demi-Lune good call. A list would work fine, such that the output is an "array of arrays".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with list comprehension, which will save you some code lines and make it more interpretable, though it won't improve the runtime, as it uses loops under the hood. Also note that by incorparating a varying length lists, you'll loose any runtime improvements of the `NumPy` library, as to do so it is being cast to `dtype=object`

```
Arr1 = np.array([9,7,3,1], dtype=object)

Arr2 = np.array([[14,6], [1], [13,2]], dtype=object)

Arr3 = np.array([0,2])

result = np.array([[Arr1[i]] if not np.sum(Arr3 == i) else Arr2[i] for i in np.arange(Arr1.size)], dtype=object)

result
```

```
OUTPUT: array([list([14, 6]), list([7]), list([13, 2]), list([1])], dtype=object)
```

Cheers

Comment: Despite the names, none of his code samples are arrays.  They are lists!

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, this is because you add arrays of different shapes, so the `numpy.array` must resort the `python`-like behavior, which is exactly storing numbers in `list` objects. That is exactly the reason I said that in this case (i.e., when using arrays of different shapes) you loose the benifits of the `NumPy` library. What is your objection?

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces a list

```
In [505]: Arr1 = [9,7,3,1]
     ...: Arr2 = [[14,6],[13,2]]
     ...: Arr3 = [0,2]
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [506]: dim1 = len(Arr1)
     ...: dim2 = len(Arr2)
     ...: dim3 = len(Arr3)
     ...: 
     ...: for i in range(dim1):
     ...:     for j in range(dim3):
     ...:         if i==Arr3[j]:
     ...:             Arr1[i] = Arr2[j]
     ...:         else:
     ...:             Arr1[i] = Arr1[i]
     ...: 
In [507]: Arr1
Out[507]: [[14, 6], 7, [13, 2], 1]
```

You could tweak that by changing to `Arr1[i] = [Arr1[i]]`

If I change `Arr1` and `Arr2` to arrays, I do get an error

```
Arr1=np.array([9,7,3,1])
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Trying to put a `np.array([14,6])` into a slot of a numeric array is not allowed.

Changing `Arr1` to object dtype, does work:

```
In [511]: Arr1=np.array(Arr1,object)
...
In [513]: Arr1
Out[513]: array([array([14,  6]), 7, array([13,  2]), 1], dtype=object)
```

So I'm surprised that you didn't either get an error, or at least some sort of change.